# Frequent lag spikes in multi-threaded code

Tags: c#, multithreading, lag

I'm attempting to make my simple C# graphics library multi-threaded. However, after the introduction of this code:

```
/* foreach (IAffector affector in affectorLookup.Values)
    affector.Update(timestep); */

taskManager.Value = timestep; taskManager.Start();

foreach (IAffector affector in affectorLookup.Values)
    taskManager.AddToQueue(affector.Update);
taskManager.StopWhenDone();
taskManager.Wait();
```

the simulation starts experiencing sharp lag-spikes, which seem to originate in TaskHandler.Run (I can't tell for sure, because adding the previous code makes my code profiler ignore anything outside TaskHandler.Run).

The task manager:

```
public class TaskManager
{
    public delegate void MethodDel(float timestep);
    private Queue<MethodDel> queue;
    private List<TaskHandler> handlers;
    private float value;


    public float Value
    {
        get
        {
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }


    public TaskManager()
    {
        this.queue = new Queue<MethodDel>();
        this.handlers = new List<TaskHandler>(System.Environment.ProcessorCount);

        for (int t = 0; t < this.handlers.Capacity; ++t)
            this.handlers.Add(new TaskHandler(this));

        this.value = 0;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.Start();
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (queue)
            queue.Clear();

        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.StopWhenDone();
    }


    public void StopWhenDone()
    {
        foreach (var handler in handlers)
            handler.StopWhenDone();
    }


    public void AddToQueue(MethodDel method)
    {
        lock (queue)
            queue.Enqueue(method);
    }


    public bool GetFromQueue(out MethodDel method)
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            if (queue.Count == 0) { method = null; return false; }

            method = queue.Dequeue();
            return true;
        }
    }


    public int GetQueueCount()
    {
        return queue.Count;
    }

    internal void Wait()
    {
        // Have to wait for them one at a time because the main thread is STA.

        WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[1];
        // for (int t = 0; t < handlers.Count; ++t)
            // waitHandles[t] = handlers[t].WaitHandle;

        // WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
        for (int t = 0; t < handlers.Count; ++t)
        { waitHandles[0] = handlers[t].WaitHandle; WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles); }
    }
}
```

And the task handler:

```
public class TaskHandler
{
    private TaskManager manager;
    private Thread thread;
    private bool stopWhenDone;
    private ManualResetEvent waitHandle;


    public ManualResetEvent WaitHandle
    {
        get
        {
            return waitHandle;
        }
    }


    public TaskHandler(TaskManager manager)
    {
        this.manager = manager;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        stopWhenDone = false;

        thread = new Thread(Run);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        thread.Start();
    }


    public void StopWhenDone()
    {
        this.stopWhenDone = true;
    }

    // Possible source of slowdown
    private void Run()
    {
        TaskManager.MethodDel curMethod;
        while (!stopWhenDone || manager.GetQueueCount() > 0)
        {
            if (manager.GetFromQueue(out curMethod))
            {
                curMethod(manager.Value);
            }
        }
        waitHandle.Set();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting a thread is a heavy operation. Not sure if it's as heavy as you are experiencing, but that could be it. Also, having all your processing run parallel can be putting a big strain on your system with possibly little benefit...

Comment: I have a dual-core, so I wouldn't think it unreasonable to expect some benefit. I'll test thread start times, thanks.

Comment: Now that's interesting. In debug or release, it can create 100,000 new Thread objects per second. However, it can Thread.Start only 100 times per second in debug - And 2,700 times per second in release.

Comment: Threads cost something like 400k cycles to start, but creating a new thread is just allocating a new stack. Personally, the design looks like it only creates as many threads as cores, then each thread just chews at the queue.

Comment: The threads were being started and exiting once per loop. I've changed it so the threads are started once and wait for input. That seems to have solved the lag problem. Now I have synchronization problems! Progress!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture that the spikes have something to do with waitHandle.Set();

I like the overall design, but I have not used WaitHandle before, so I am unsure how this interacts with your design.